# Autocomplete list is not being populated

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As per the code below, I am attempting to populate my autocomplete textbox with a list. When I `console.log()` the list, I get the expected result, but when I add the list to my autocomplete function it does not work as expected, I only see the list name as a suggestion. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The code:

```
var childData; // Holds Objects
var exercises = []; // Push exercise names into this
// Obtain Exercises
function exerciseQueries() { 
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('exercises'); // Reference equal to exercises node
    ref.orderByChild('name').on('value', function (snapshot) { // Order by name of exercise
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) { // Loop, on each hit
            // childData will be the actual contents of the child
            childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData);    
            exercises.push(childData.name);
        });

    });
}
exerciseQueries(); // Execute function


$(function () {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {childData: null}
    });
    console.log(exercises);    
});
```

I have tried passing an object (childData), and the list (exercises); but neither are working. I also tried the source argument instead of data, but no luck. Can anyone assist?

EDIT updated code (Same error)

```
function exerciseQueries() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('exercises'); // Reference equal to exercises node
    ref.orderByChild('name').on('value', function (snapshot) { // Order by name of exercise
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) { // Loop, on each hit
            // childData will be the actual contents of the child
            childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData);
            exercises.push(childData.name);
        });
        $(function () {
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                data: {childData}
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: The `on` is asynchronous. Move the `$(function () {...}` to immediately after the `snapshot.forEach`

Comment: @cartant I am still getting the same error, I updated my original post to show the new code; did I make an error?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something with the `exercises` array? If you log it before `$(function () {...}` you should see that it's not empty - as long as there's stuff in the database - then you just need to do something with it.

Comment: @cartant Yessir I tried. The console.log(exercises) shows all three exercises from my database. But when I type those names in my autocomplete field, they are not showing. It is only showing "exercises", but not its contents; this is where I am lost.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unfamiliar with jQuery and the `autocomplete` thing. At least this has fixed the first part of your problem, though.